# How would I be able to modify it so that the results should show only if the count of the total countries in the region is larger than 15?

Tags: mysql, sql

Query

```
SELECT Region AS "Region Name", COUNT(*)AS "Total Countries"
FROM country
GROUP BY Region
ORDER BY Region DESC;
```

Comment: Look up the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Add `HAVING COUNT(*) > 15` at the end.

Comment: How would it look like is SQL format?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this

```
SELECT Region AS `Region Name`, COUNT(*) AS `Total Countries`
FROM country
GROUP BY Region
HAVING `Total Countries` > 15
ORDER BY Region DESC;
```